# char array to int array and delete an char c#

Tags: c#

im trying to make a song in beeps with pi and i need to delet the dot (pi1[1]) (*) and i need to convert the char array pi1 to int array pi2 (**)

```
double a = Math.PI;
string b=a.ToString();
char[] pi1 = b.ToCharArray();
* pi1[1] = '0';
int[] pi2;
for (int i = 0; i < pi1.Length; i++)
{
**    pi2[i] = int.Parse(pi1[i].ToString());
}
//for (int i = 0; i > 40; i++)
//{
//    Console.Beep(100*c, 100);
//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part that seems to be causing the problem is the need to not try to convert the decimal point. You can do this using `string.Replace`.

The following is a one-line solution to get the first 15 digits of pi as an array of integers:

```
int[] piDigits = Math.PI.ToString()
                 .Replace(".", "")
                 .Select(c => c - '0')
                 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `pi1` consists entirely of the characters `0`–`9`, you could parse it into an `int` array using:

```
int[] pi2 = pi1.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();
```

Comment: Error The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: @user3159855: Try the updated version of the code above.

Comment: ohhh i understood there is a . in pi1[1] so i think that why it doesnt work, do you know how do i delete pi1[1]?